# Cannot access my redis instance

Tags: ubuntu, redis

I'm  having a problem with redis recently. My setup is the following:

- Ubuntu 11.11
- Redis 2.4.2 (not from the repo, but compiled)

The thing is, that I suddenly cannot access the redis server at all! It launches just fine the log looks like this:

`[23759] 14 Nov 14:37:15 - DB 0: 473 keys (0 volatile) in 512 slots HT.

[23759] 14 Nov 14:37:15 - DB 1: 2882 keys (0 volatile) in 4096 slots HT.

[23759] 14 Nov 14:37:15 - DB 4: 6 keys (0 volatile) in 8 slots HT.

[23759] 14 Nov 14:37:15 - DB 8: 6094 keys (0 volatile) in 8192 slots HT.

[23759] 14 Nov 14:37:15 - 0 clients connected (0 slaves), 26706728 bytes in use`

As soon as I try to connect with e.g. `redis-cli` I'll get a timeout.

I already set the timeout to 0 and checked the open ports via nmap, everything seems fine. Does anyone have similar problems with redis and/or Ubuntu 11.11? I suspect upstart to be the problem actually ...

Answer (score 3):

I have compiled, installed, and heavily used Redis on multiple Ubuntu 11.11 instances. It seems one of three things is likely occurring.

1. Redis is running as a daemon. Upstart doesn't play well with daemonized (backgrounded) processes. Modify your redis.conf and make sure you are NOT running Redis as a daemon. Otherwise upstart will think the process died and will try to start it again, which can screw things up.
2. There are problems with your redis.conf or you are not executing Redis with the redis.conf file you think you are. Check your redis.conf and make sure you have properly enabled either TCP connections by binding to an IP and port, or that you have enabled unix sockets.
3. You have configured Redis to listen on a non-standard port or through a unix socket and `redis-cli` is not being passed the correct port or socket. Or, you are using sockets and the user you are running `redis-cli` with does not have permission to read/write to the socket.

Here is the functioning upstart script I use in my development environments, which I place in `/etc/init/redis.conf`: https://gist.github.com/1297014

Here is the Redis configuration file which I usually store at `/opt/redis/redis.conf` along with the redis executables (though storing the conf file at `/etc/redis.conf` would likely be more standard): https://gist.github.com/1368914

Beyond a couple small changes my development environments use the stock redis.conf. The only change I had to make to support using upstart to manage redis was to set `daemonize no`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll be trying this out.

Comment: Regarding (1): Upstart has the "expect fork" and "expect daemon" directives. I'm struggling to get it all working but don't understand why it wouldn't. A strace run shows that redis forks twice in daemon form, but I still can't quite figure it out.